# Gaussian blur with high radius

Tags: krita

Gaussian blur filter in Krita has sliders for selecting horizontal and vertical radius, but they only go to 100 px. Is there any way to set higher values?

I already tried to type in the value directly, but it didn't actually change the value and resulted in the shown value being completely disconnected from the slider position.

Version 2.9.11 running on win 10

Editing the value manually:
[image]

After hitting enter, it goes back to 100:
[image]

Comment: I tried it. Krita allowed 1000 px radiuses with the sliders but above 100 px settings made the rendering very slow. In my low end PC 1000 px Gaussian blur took about 2 minutes. The image was 1600 x 1200 pixels RGB, 8bit/color/pixel. Are you sure that you didn't only give up waiting the result?

Comment: @user287001 Can you specify the steps (where do you click and so on)? Maybe I am doing something wrong here, but it always changes back to 100 px and the resulting image is decidedly a 100 px blur.

Comment: @user287001 no wornder doing a gaussian blur on a object naively is 100 slower versus doing it 100 pix, unless you go to a frequency space like fourier space. But this is commonly not doen in graohics apps.